# Social/nightlife in the US (NYC, Boston, Chicago) through hostels

Tags: usa, hostels, solo-travel, socializing

So I'll be staying in hostels around these areas on the East Coast soon. I'm just wondering if staying in hostels gives you adequate opportunity to meet people and go out at night to clubs and stuff? Is it a common culture for people to go out together? I guess the other alternative would be to go out by myself and I guess try to meet people at a bar, but it's not something I've really done before.

Comment: Check out [How to make the most of my first hostel stay](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8908/108).

Comment: I do not think there is not common culture in hostels when it comes to social/night life. It is variant as in any other place. Some people are social, some are not. Some have plans to be stuck to, some are like you seeking for fun and social life.

Comment: The tips Ankur linked to are probably valid as [it seems US hostels are not that different from hostels elsewhere](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2458/hostels-in-us-vs-europe). To find out which  hostels in your destination cities are especially good for socialising / nightlife, I think your best bet is to go through reviews on booking sites such as Hostelworld.